# Integral under Diffeomorphsim, sign of Jacobian

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification

I'm reading Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds on page 264:

> Let $V,U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, with respective coordinates $y^1,...,y^n$ and $x^1,...,x^n$, with a diffeomorphism $T:V\to U$ and an $n$-from $\omega=fdx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n$ defined on $U$. Let $J$ be the jacobian matrix of $T$. then you can show $\int_V T^*\omega=\int_V(f\circ T)$det$(J(T))dy^1...dy^n$. From change of variables, we know $\int_U\omega=\int_Ufdx^1...dx^n=\int_V(f\circ T)|$det$(J(T))|dy^1...dy^n$. He concludes $\int_VT^*\omega=\pm\int_U\omega$.

But doesn't this require that det$(J(T))$ has constant sign throughout $V?$ It isn't assumed explicitly, and the only other assumption is that $U,V$ are connected. So why does det$(J(T))$ have constant sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $T$ is a diffeomorphism, $J(T)$ is always an invertible matrix. Therefore $\det(J(T))$ can never be $0$. The idea is then that, since $\det(J(T))$ can never be $0$, it is either going to be positive all the time or negative all the time (otherwise it would have to cross $0$). To make this precise, you use the connectedness. Specifically, the sets $\{p\in V : \det(J(T))(p)>0\}$ and $\{p\in V : \det(J(T))(p)<0\}$  are disjoint open sets which cover $V$; connectedness then implies one of them must be empty.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking, could you also say, since $f$ is smooth, det$(J(T))$ is smooth, hence continuous. Then using contentedness, intermediate value theorem implies det$(J(T))$ has one sign, otherwise there's a point $p$ such that det$(J(T))=0$, contradicting diffeomorphism?

Comment: That is another way to say it, yes!

Comment: A simple and concise answer.